Pasting clipboard contents to Google Sheet using AppleScript
I am trying extract the text from an image and then paste the text contents into a googlesheet using AppleScript.
The topmost part of the code GetImageText was sourced from code I found somewhere (sorry - I forget where!) and that seems to be working fine. I know this because I’ve logged the contents of the clipboard and that bit of QA confirms that the text is being extracted successfully.
set SheetTitle to "Stuff I Need"

use framework "AppKit" 
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "Vision"
use scripting additions
on getImageText(imagePath)
    -- Get image content
    set theImage to current application's NSImage's alloc()'s initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath
    
    -- Set up request handler using image's raw data
    set requestHandler to current application's VNImageRequestHandler's alloc()'s initWithData:(theImage's TIFFRepresentation()) options:(current application's NSDictionary's alloc()'s init())
    
    -- Initialize text request
    set theRequest to current application's VNRecognizeTextRequest's alloc()'s init()
    
    -- Perform the request and get the results
    requestHandler's performRequests:(current application's NSArray's arrayWithObject:(theRequest)) |error|:(missing value)
    
    set theResults to theRequest's results()
    
    set theArray to current application's NSMutableArray's new()
    repeat with aResult in theResults
        (theArray's addObject:(((aResult's topCandidates:1)'s objectAtIndex:0)'s |string|()))
    end repeat
    return (theArray's componentsJoinedByString:linefeed) as text -- return a string
end getImageText

tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 1
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if title of t contains the SheetTitle then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                set GoogleTab to i
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

set theFile to POSIX path of "/Users/[yourname]/Desktop/Screenshots/Screen-01.jpeg"

set the clipboard to ""
set the clipboard to getImageText(theFile) as text
delay 3

tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set the active tab index of the front window to GoogleTab
    delay 3 
    tell application "System Events"
        delay 3
        keystroke "v" using command down
        delay 3
    end tell    
end tell

Sometimes this works, and the values paste successfully in google sheets, and other times - it just doesn’t.
What am I missing? HELP and THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

GetImageText was sourced from code I found somewhere Possibly from MacScripter.net: Image (PNG) to Text Through AppleScript, and StackOverflow macOS: How to access the Live Text OCR functionality from AppleScript/JXA?

Yes! Thank you @Tedinoz

To the stack overflow folks, I just ditched google chrome and did everything in safari. Problem solved.
